# Move a selection to specific X,Y position in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I move a selection to a specific XY position within the canvas in Photoshop?

Currently, the only way I can find is to just eyeball it with the guides and/or mouse position. I want to specify the exact X and Y coordinates.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With your active selection, go to *Edit » Free Transform*. This is the same as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> on OS X.

Then, in the toolbar above your image, select the angle point where you want to set the coordinates. In my example, it is the center of the selection.

[image]

Now, enter the X and Y coordinates you want your selection to be at. If you want to move your selection *relative* to the previous location, toggle the triangle button.

Hit Enter or click the "Commit transform" button (which looks like a checkmark).

Comment: This is great, but it moves the selected content; what I really want is to position a fixed-size marquee precisely.

Answer (score 1):

did you turn on the rulers? then set them for pixels.
http://www.itechies.net/tutorials/photoshop/index-pid-ruler.htm

Answer (score 0):

With your selection active, go to the menubar and choose *Select > Transform Selection*, then in the toolbar you'll have access to the transform numeric entry fields for X/Y position, width/height dimensions, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

tick the autoselect box again